# Find out what is setting local storage

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage

I have noticed today that in every site I visit there is a new key value pair called `randid` in my local storage in chrome.

I searched it but I couldn't find anything on it. I noticed it as I was checking local storage on an app I am working on and it only appeared today.

I have not installed any new plugins prior to it appearing.

Here is an example:

[image]

**EDIT**

I just checked on another machine and the same thing is happening there. I tried logging out of my google account and reinstalling thinking it may have been a chrome sync thing but it is still there.

Is anyone else able to see it in their local storage?

Answer (score 4):

So I traced it back to "Pop up blocker for Chrome" chrome extension.

If you disable and delete the local storage item for each site and refresh it is no longer there. Enable it again and it returns.

Comment: I confirm that this entry in localStorage has stopped appearing after deleting the mentioned browser extension.